# Оptimal strategy when throwing dice

Tags: statistics, probability

Given a dice, you can throw it no more than three times, and you can stop at any time. How should you act so that on average you get as many as possible in the last throw?

Comment: [Cross Validated Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) would be a more appropriate place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Using backward induction:  suppose there are only 2 throws instead of 3.  You roll the first dice, and the decision should be to keep a 4,5,6 and to roll again on a 1,2,3 (in which case the expected value on the second throw will be 3.5).  But then the expected value of the 2 throw game is 1/6 * 6 + 1/6 * 5 + 1/6 * 4 + 1/2 * 3.5 = 4.25.

Hence, if you have a 3-throw game, on the first throw you will keep a 5 or a 6, and you will throw again a 1,2,3 or 4 because the latter produce a result less than the 2 throw game is worth.

Comment: I don't quite understand your suggestion

Comment: Сan you explain more clearly and step by step?

Comment: I don’t think so.  Perhaps you need to study probability and expected value.

Answer (score 2):

Your decision is  based on the expected value of the following throws. If it is higher than what you have right now, you throw again. In a two throw game, you would use the second throw if your first throw is 1, 2 or 3 since $E[T_2] = 3.5$.

For a three throw game you can use make the same strategy but the decision rule after 1st throw is slightly more difficult to come up with. You should use backward induction. You would use the 3rd throw if the 2nd is 1, 2 or 3 (see above).
So you keep the 2nd throw in case of 4, 5 or 6. The expected value of the 2nd and 3rd throw combined is $E[T_2\text{ or }T_3]=\frac{1}{6}6 + \frac{1}{6} 5 + \frac{1}{6} 4 + 0.5 E[T_3] = \frac{1}{6}6 + \frac{1}{6} 5 + \frac{1}{6} 4 + \frac{1}{2}3.5 = 4.25$.
So for the 1st throw you only keep 5 or 6.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard interview question in quantitative finance. [This article](https://medium.com/@whystudying/dice-game-optimized-stopping-strategy-59faa0862d8e) provides a clear description, as does Mark Joshi's "Quant Interview Questions and Answers".

Answer (score -2):

Hi and welcome to the forum. Given that the expected value of a single throw is SUM(1:6)/6 = 3.5, I would always reroll (up to 3 times) as long as I get a 3 and below. I would stop so long as I get a 4 and above.

Comment: could you explain this in more detail?

Comment: @User_001, each throw of the dice is independent (the first throw does not affect the second and the first and second do not affect the third throw) and can only result in the outcomes of 1 to 6 per throw. Each time you throw a dice, you will get a value of (1+2+3+4+5+6)/6 = 3.5 ex-ante. The 1 to 6 in the numerator are the possible results of the throw and 6 in the denominator is the number of outcomes. Therefore, it is only logical to reroll if you get below 3.5 (3 and below) for a roll.